# Как сделать регистрацию для всех во fronted? Yii2-advanced

Tags: yii2

Сейчас при попытке открыть вкладку 'Signup' меня перебрасывает на 'login' (http://site.com/site/login) но войти может только 1 user из базы данных -админ, т.е больше никто зарегистрироваться не может.

SiteController (fronted)

```html
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use medeyacom\blog\models\Blog;
use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;

/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout','signup'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['signup'],
                        'allow' => true,
                       /* 'roles' => ['?'],*/
                         'roles' => ['canAdmin'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        #$blogs = Blog::find()->where(['status_id'=>1])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->all();

       $blogs = Blog::find()->andWhere(['status_id'=>1])->orderBy('sort')->all();
        #$blogs = Blog::find()->where(['status_id'=>1])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_ASC])->all();


        return $this->render('index',['blogs'=>$blogs]);
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs out the current user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'There was an error sending your message.');
            }

            return $this->refresh();
        } else {
            return $this->render('contact', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
  /*  public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                    return $this->goHome();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }*/


 public function actionSignup() {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this ->goHome();
        }
        $model =new SignupForm ();
        return $this ->render ('signup', compact ('model'));

        }

    /**
     * Requests password reset.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionRequestPasswordReset()
    {
        $model = new PasswordResetRequestForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Check your email for further instructions.');

                return $this->goHome();
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Sorry, we are unable to reset password for the provided email address.');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('requestPasswordResetToken', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Resets password.
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @return mixed
     * @throws BadRequestHttpException
     */
    public function actionResetPassword($token)
    {
        try {
            $model = new ResetPasswordForm($token);
        } catch (InvalidParamException $e) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException($e->getMessage());
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $model->resetPassword()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'New password saved.');

            return $this->goHome();
        }

        return $this->render('resetPassword', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

signup (fronted/views/site)

```html
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model \frontend\models\SignupForm */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

$this->title = 'Signup';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-signup">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>Пожалуйста, заполните следующие поля для регистрации.:</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup']); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Регистрация', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
                </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Signform (fronted/models)

```html
<?php
namespace frontend\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use common\models\User;

/**
 * Signup form
 */
class SignupForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $email;
    public $password;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['username', 'trim'],
            ['username', 'required'],
            ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
            ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

            ['email', 'trim'],
            ['email', 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

            ['password', 'required'],
            ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return User|null the saved model or null if saving fails
     */

    public function attributeLabels () {
        return [
        'username' => 'Логин',
        'password' => 'Пароль',
        'email' => 'email',
        ];
}


    public function signup()
    {
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return null;
        }
        
        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        
        return $user->save() ? $user : null;
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

main.php (common/config)

```html
<?php
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'timeZone' => 'Europe/Moscow',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
            /* 'robotEmail' => '',*/
            /*'robotName' => 'Robot'*/
        ],
            
         'image' => [
           'class' => 'yii\image\ImageDriver',
          'driver' => 'GD',  //GD or Imagick
          ],
                
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
            'cache' => 'cache'
        ],
    
    ],
    'on beforeAction' => function($event){ //цепляемся за событие перед запуском экшена
      Yii::$app->controller->attachBehavior('',[ //цепляем к текущему контролеру поведение
          'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(), //указываем класс поведения
          'except' => ['login','error','register'], 
         //исключим из правила экшены login и error, так как они должны быть доступны всем
          'rules' => [
              [
                  'allow' => true, //разрешаем доступ
                  'roles' => ['@'], //'@' только зарегистрированным пользователям или замените на 'admin',  что бы только админам позволить
              ],
          ],
      ]);
    },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере в behaviors вернуть всё как было. Разкомментировать закомментированную строку `/* 'roles' => ['?'],*/` и удалить добавленную строчку с `'roles' => ['canAdmin'],`

Comment: нет, это ничего не меняет(

Comment: незарегистрированный пользователь не может войти в signup?

Comment: да, так - в signup может попасть только зарег.пользователь. 'rules' у меня также прописаны в common/config/main  - файл прикреплю к вопросу.

Comment: в `common/config/main.php` в except нужно добавить signup - `'except' => ['login', 'error', 'register', 'signup'],`

Answer (score 0):

В main.php (common/config) вместо '@' указываем '?'

```html
  'rules' => [
              [
                  'allow' => true, //разрешаем доступ
                  'roles' => ['?'], //'@' только зарегистрированным пользователям или замените на 'admin',  что бы только админам позволить
              ],
```